# Downloading .pdf file from FTP using a Python Script

Tags: python, pdf, ftp, download

I am able to download files from the FTP using the ftplib in Python, but this is like I hard code the name the name of the file(R.pdf) and this downloads only (R.pdf), is there a way to download all files in the FTP with the extension .PDF to my local system using Python. I am able to do this in Shell by just using *.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace host, user and password with your credentials,
and 'public_html/soleil' with the address of the directory in which are the PDF files you want to be downloaded,
in the following code and it should be OK I think.

```
from ftplib import *
from os import listdir
from os.path import getsize


ftp_dt = FTP(host,user,password)
ftp_pi = FTP(host,user,password)
print '\n- Ouverture de connection et logging : OK'


ftp_dt.cwd('public_html/soleil')
ftp_pi.cwd('public_html/soleil')


def func(content, li = [0], la = [], si = [0], memname = ['']):
    if name!=memname[0]:
        memname[0],li[0:1],la[:],si[0:1] = name,[0],[],[0]
    li[0] = li[0] + 1
    si[0] = si[0] + len(content)
    la.append(str(len(content)))
    if li[0]%8==0:
        print '  '.join(la) +\
              '   total: '+str(li[0])+' chunks,  '+str(si[0])+' bytes'
        la[:] = []
    f.write(content)


li_files = []
for name in ftp_dt.nlst():
    try:
        ftp_dt.size(name)
        if name not in ('.','..') and name[-4:]=='.pdf':
            li_files.append(name)
    except:
        pass


if li_files:
    for name in li_files:
        print '\n- Downloading  '+name

        with open('E:\\PDF\\DOWNS\\'+name,'wb') as f:
            ftp_pi.retrbinary('RETR '+name,func)

        if getsize('E:\\PDF\\DOWNS\\'+name)==ftp_dt.size(name):
            print '   OK !  Download of complete  '+repr(name)+'  SUCCEEDED'
        else:
            print '   FAILURE !! :  '+name+'  only partially downloaded'
else:
    print '\nThere is no PDF file in this FTP directory'


ftp_dt.quit()
ftp_pi.quit()
```

Two connexions **ftp_dt** and **ftp_pi** are defined for “Data Transfers“ and “Protocol Interpretation“ because FTP protocol is based on two channels, one for the commands and the other for..... guess what ?

The **func()** function is used as callback in the fonction **retrbinary()**

It could be just

```
def func(content):
    f.write()
```

but I played a bit with the possibilities of default variables of a function.

One thing I don’t understand well: how can this code work while the reference **f** in **func()** is only defined in the text of code after the definition of **func()** .   But I tested it and it works !

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to an `FTP` server I can try this but a cursory look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html) indicates that this is not possible.

You can, however, obtain a list of files on the remote end with the [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.dir) or [`nlst`](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst) commands and then fetch each file in a loop.

Comment: I am able to do this with the for loop if i get details of the PDF file in the FTP. 

A = ('111.pdf', '222.pdf', '333.pdf', '444.pdf')

ftp = ftplib.FTP("###.###.###.###")
ftp.login("*********", "***********")
ftp.cwd("/Dir")


for i in A:
    
    try:
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + i ,open(i, 'wb').write)
    except:
        print "Error"

Answer (score 0):

use two python modules `glob` and `wget`. Your snippet could look like this

```
import glob
import wget

list_to_download = glob.glob(url+'*.pdf')

for file in list_to_download:
    wget.download(file)
```